# How to detect end of page in WebView with Google doc viewer to show PDF?

Tags: android, pdf, webview, google-docs

I'm working on a feature where I need to enable/allow a consent checkbox with a button when a user reaches the end of the WebView page(by scrolling), unfortunately currently not getting any scroll callbacks when I use Google Doc Viewer with WebView.

Sample Google doc URL,
https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf

Code snippet I'm using to detect end of page,

```
    binding.wvPdfViewer.setOnScrollChangedCallback(object : OnScrollChangedCallback {
    override fun onScroll(l: Int, t: Int, oldl: Int, oldt: Int) {
        var r1 = binding.wvPdfViewer.computeVerticalScrollRange();
        var r2 = binding.wvPdfViewer.computeVerticalScrollExtent();
        if (t == (r1 - r2)) {
            Log.d("TESTTT","REACHED END OF THE PAGE")
        }
     }
   })
```

What are the fixes I can do to achieve it or any other suggestions? Please let me know if I need to add any more details to the question.

Comment: Hi @Ajay have you get any solution for this?

Comment: Hi @RahulMishra, No I didn't get a solution, so decided to have our own backend pdf processor, which attaches consent to the end of pdf. Couldn't afford a PDF third-party library due to huge size.